# Why did Windows 10 upgrade break VS 2017 with IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10

Did the latest Windows 10 upgrade on 8/27/2019. That broke Outlook 2016, but an Office Repair tool fixed that.

Now my VS Community 2017 can't run a Web project because IIS Express won't start. Says some other app is using the port, but SysInternals and netstat -ano say otherwise. In the Windows application log, an error for Clr4IntegratedAppPool always fires before the IIS error.

I have tried all of the following:

> - Repair VS 2017 (took hours to download gigs of stuff; what was this, an entire reinstall?)
> - Uninstall/reinstall IIS Express and reboot, reboot, reboot.
> - Delete the folder My Documents/IIS Express.
> - Delete the hidden project file .vs/config/applicationhost.config.
> - Changed the port number in the VS project properties, on the Web tab.
> - Ran this command: netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
> - I created a new web project and it ran fine with IIS Express. But after that, the old  project still could not keep IIS Express running.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When I compared the csproj files for the new project that worked and the old one that had stopped working, I found that the new one had a lot of IIS-related stuff that was absent from the old one. I copied it from the old to the new, and it worked. However, it only worked with the new port number. Haven't gotten the old one to work, but I'll gladly settle for that!

> ```
>     <WebProjectProperties>
>       <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
>       <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
>       <DevelopmentServerPort>57919</DevelopmentServerPort>
>       <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
>       <IISUrl>http://localhost:57919/</IISUrl>
>       <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
>       <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
>       <CustomServerUrl>
>       </CustomServerUrl>
>       <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
>     </WebProjectProperties>
> ```